# AgGrid JSON date column, sorting filtering is slow for huge data

Tags: date, ag-grid

I have a JSON date column in AgGrid with 20K + records. I am using a date comparator to sort dates. Is there a better way then below to sort such date type as i am experiencing slowness in my application while sorting and filtering for huge data set.

**For Sorting**

```
 comparator: function (date1, date2) {
                var date1Number = fnDateToComparableNumber(moment(date1).toDate());
                var date2Number = fnDateToComparableNumber(moment(date2).toDate());

                if ((date1Number === null || isNaN(date1Number)) && (date2Number === null || isNaN(date2Number))) {
                    return 0;
                }
                if (date1Number === null || isNaN(date1Number)) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (date2Number === null || isNaN(date2Number)) {
                    return 1;
                }

                return date1Number - date2Number;
            }
```

**For Filtering**

```
filterParams: {
                //applyButton: true,
                clearButton: true,
                // provide comparator function
                comparator: function (filterLocalDateAtMidnight, cellValue) {
                    // We create a Date object for comparison against the filter date
                    if (cellValue == '') {
                        return 1;
                    }

                    var cellDate = moment(cellValue).toDate();

                    // Now that both parameters are Date objects, we can compare
                    if (cellDate < filterLocalDateAtMidnight) {
                        return -1;
                    } else if (cellDate > filterLocalDateAtMidnight) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            },
```

Note:

1. I am using moment for date manipulations
2. JSON date is required for excel export. Else processCellCallback is expensive in case of big data. 
   I have done some hack for excel format else excel will display date as number.
3. We have enterprise license for Ag-Grid

Comment: did you find any solution

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems at least for sorting by date. Do not use moment for parsing dates. It is way to slow for the amount of data you are using. Instead use Date():

```
 comparator: function (date1, date2) {
                var date1Number = fnDateToComparableNumber(Date(date1));
                var date2Number = fnDateToComparableNumber(Date(date2));

                if ((date1Number === null || isNaN(date1Number)) && (date2Number === null || isNaN(date2Number))) {
                    return 0;
                }
                if (date1Number === null || isNaN(date1Number)) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (date2Number === null || isNaN(date2Number)) {
                    return 1;
                }

                return date1Number - date2Number;
            }
```

Maybe you'll need to parse the date manually but you are still way faster than using moment.

Answer (score 0):

For sorting dates `valueFormatter` function helps. This worked for me and didn't slow down while sorting large datasets.

```
{
 headerName: 'Date',
 field: 'date',
 valueFormatter: params => dateFormatter(params.value),
 sortable: true
}
```